# JavaScript delete values from array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am relatively new to JavaScript and I am build a little app which randomly generates a card from a set of 52 cards (I stored all possibilities in an array). But I want to make sure that the same card can not be generated twice. I was not able to find a way to do so.

```
var cardType = ["A♠","2♠","3♠","4♠","5♠","6♠","7♠","8♠","9♠","10♠","J♠","Q♠","K♠"];

function generateCard()
{
var card = cardType[Math.round(Math.random() * (cardType.length - 1))];
}
```

The spade symbols are not actually in my array I just put it in for visibility.

Answer (score 3):

Keep track of already generated cards, check to see if the newly generated card already exists, and if it does, generate a new card :

```
var already_generated = [];
var cardType = ["A♠","2♠","3♠","4♠","5♠"...];

function generateCard() {
    var card = cardType[Math.round(Math.random() * (cardType.length - 1))];

    if ( already_generated.indexOf(card) == -1 ) {
        already_generated.push(card);
    }else{
        if (already_generated.length < cardType.length) generateCard();
    }
}
```

Older browsers will need a shim for `Array.indexOf`, which can be found at [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf)

As a sidenote, the original array could be sliced, but this just seems easier unless you for some reason *have* to change the original array !

Comment: If you generate all the cards and call generating fn, your execution will get into trouble

Comment: @OzrenTkalčecKrznarić - Yes it will, I didn't add a check for that, as it seemed rather obvious, but I'll add it now.

Comment: the fundamental problem, with this code (and the one posted in the question) is that you define your array inside the function, meaning it's reset every time the function is called, meaning you have to keep track of what cards you already have. see my answer for a much more efficient solution

Comment: @Dogoku  - If it floats your boat, I'll move it for you.

Comment: I think this algorithm is horrible.  It'll work OK for a few cards, but it'll be really inefficient the more cards you generate.  Being recursive it could even cause stack overflow errors.

Comment: The max amount of cards will be 52 do you think this will already cause a problem?

Comment: @DisMeJP Yes, I do.   You should just take the deck, shuffle it, and take one card at a time until the deck is empty, per my answer.

Comment: I don't, for 52 cards it will work just fine, and unless you're using Netscape Navigator 1.0 the chances of a stack overflow is about zero, even if just shuffling the deck once is way more efficient.

Comment: @adeneo OK, it probably won't crash, but from a CS algorithm efficiency perspective this really is nasty (IMHO).  If a coder working for me wrote it this way, they'd be up for review.

Answer (score 3):

Pre shuffle the array and pop one card at time, from the array

```
var cardType = ["A♠","2♠","3♠","4♠","5♠","6♠","7♠","8♠","9♠","10♠","J♠","Q♠","K♠"];

//shuffles array
cardType.sort(function() { return 0.5 - Math.random() });

function generateCard()
{    
    return cardType.pop();
}
```

When you get `undefined` it means you got all the cards

Comment: Good answer, +1 from me

Comment: I'm not convinced by that `sort` helper function - it's using a non-deterministic comparator to an `O(n log n)` function, when a decent  Knuth-Fisher-Yates shuffle will work in `O(n)` time.

Comment: to be perfectly honest, i just copied the function from http://css-tricks.com/snippets/javascript/shuffle-array/ cause performance doesnt matter when its 13 items and a one-off operation

Comment: @Dogoku find a better site - whoever wrote that doesn't know what they're doing.

Comment: @Dogoku FWIW, algorithm #1 on that page appears to be the correct Knuth shuffle, but the implementor deserves to be shot for using `parseInt` to round the random number!

Comment: You actually got me curious. I'm setting up a jsperf, to see the difference :P

Answer (score 0):

I would just:

- make your ordered set of cards (i.e. a "pack")
- use an [effective shuffling algorithm](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/12/the-danger-of-naivete.html) to make a "deck" from the "pack"
- use `deck.pop()` to just take successive cards from that deck

Having an abstraction to represent a deck of cards will likely prove useful as you develop your application.  It might seem like overkill now, but it'll be worth it in the long run.  Done properly, it should be re-usable in other projects too.

Answer (score -2):

Use the delete keyword.

Sample:

```
var x = [1,2,3];
delete x[1]; // delete element '2'
for (i in x) { 
  console.log(x[i]); // outputs 1, 3
}
```

Comment: But the length is still the same, messing up the random card generation.

Comment: bad answer on two counts - `delete` on an array will just make the element undefined, not remove it, and you shouldn't use `for ... in` on arrays, only on objects.

Comment: I know where you are heading, bit please give OP a real example

Comment: `for (var i in x)` as well, or you're not declaring `i`.

Comment: The delete operator removes a property from an object. That's it. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete for more info.